# Какой вариант проверки условия наиболее производителен?

Tags: java, производительность, if, benchmark

```
int a = 0;
String b = "0";
```

1. вариант:

   ```
   if(String.valueOf(a).equals(b)) {}
   ```
2. вариант:

   ```
   if(Integer.valueOf(b) == a) {}
   ```

Comment: `b` - гарантированно является числом?

Comment: да . b - это всегда число

Comment: Заполненные массивы размером в 1000000 элементов перебрало в следующем соотношении: 1 - 186 мс ; 2 - 47мс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример кода:

```
    int[] a = new int[1000000];
    String[] b = new String[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = "8";
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        if(String.valueOf(a[i]).equals(b[i])){

        }
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        if(Integer.valueOf(b[i]) == a[i]){

        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Результаты в мс (4 запуска):

1 вариант: 203 | 156 | 484 | 140

2 вариант: 32 | 47 | 47 | 32

Comment: У вас пустые `if`, которые ничего не делают. Я не уверен, но, возможно, что компилятор это оптимизирует и сравнение будет не таким, каким вы ожидали его получить

Comment: я заполнил блоки, но результат такой же

Answer (score 3):

Немного результатов измерений:

```
# JMH version: 1.20
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# CPU: Intel Core i7-6700 3.40 GHz (4 cores, 8 threads)

Benchmark                         Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.stringValueOfInteger  avgt   15  26.363 ± 0.112  ns/op
MyBenchmark.integerValueOfString  avgt   15  13.990 ± 0.129  ns/op
MyBenchmark.integerToString       avgt   15  26.247 ± 0.260  ns/op
MyBenchmark.integerPlusString     avgt   15  15.541 ± 0.227  ns/op
```

Код бенчмарка:

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setup() {
        a = 0;
        b = "0";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stringValueOfInteger(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(String.valueOf(a).equals(b));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void integerValueOfString(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(Integer.valueOf(b) == a);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void integerToString(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(Integer.toString(a).equals(b));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void integerPlusString(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(("" + a).equals(b));
    }
}
```

Пояснения к результату:

- самый быстрый вариант (~14 нс на операцию): `Integer.valueOf(b) == a`
  (да, `Integer.parseInt(b) == a)` показывает примерно тот же результат)
- чуть менее быстрый (~15.5 нс на операцию): `("" + a).equals(b)`
- разница в ~10 нс, пожалуй, не особо важна для вашего приложения

Comment: На практике разница оказалась ощутима